# Getting path of exported Excel file in downloads folder it's getting path while working on my machine but it's not getting path on client machine

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side

I have an `ExportExcel` function which exports an Excel file in the downloads folder but I have to apply wrapping to some column for that I am using Syncfusion.XlsIO library and for applying wrapping first we need to open that file now problem is file is getting correct path on my machine and its getting wrapped but on client machine it's not getting wrapped because i guess its not getting correct path here is my code for getting path:

```
await RecurringTasksGrid.ExportToExcelAsync(exportProperties);

string fileName = exportProperties.FileName;
string exportPath = $"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\Downloads"}/{fileName}";
```

I am trying to getting path on client machine too but it's not getting

Comment: A Blazor app has a frontend and backend.  The front end is a client/server connection and the backend is the server/database connection.  A credential is passed from the frontend client to the server and then is used to connect to the database.  The server has no access to the client files system.  Likewise the client has no access to the server or backend database.  Any data passed between client and server must be transmitted.  The only exception is if the file is on a network server where both the client and server have access to the files.